# Ignore border with layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, border

How can I tell a component/layout to ignore the border of the parent component when being laid out?

For example, I have a 2px border on every side, but it should not cause the components inside to be shifted by 2px to the right and down. (effectively reducing the containers size by 4px width and height)

Comment: A more specific question would yield some answers. E.g. what toolkit you are using etc.

Comment: Is it a `Border` or insets or margins of the component or insets/padding by the layout?

Comment: @anttix As I specified in the tags, it's a Swing related question.

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's a `Border`.

Comment: Then there's no way to achieve it.  The `Border` insets are included as part of the calculation for the components `preferred/minimum/maximumSize` - The only possible choices you have are to write a layout manager of your own that does this, remove the border, create your own border that has no insets or "fix" the `preferred/minimum/maximumSize` calculations to remove the border insets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CompoundBorder`:

```
Border outer = new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.RED);
Border inner = new EmptyBorder(-2, -2, -2, -2);
CompoundBorder border = new CompoundBorder(outer, inner);
panel.setBorder(border);
```

The other option is to use a nested layout:

```
JPanel outer = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
outer.setBorder( new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.RED) );
JPanel inner = new JPanel();
outer.add(inner);
```

Yes this will still take up the same space as your original approach, but at least all the components will be laid out based on the size of the inner panel.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather strange requirement, so I would urge a great abundance of caution - try to avoid doing this if you can.

You could override the border's insets, which wouldn't affect the painting of the component or border, only where the component is painted

```
LineBorder border = new LineBorder(Color.orange, 10){
    Insets overridenInset = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return overridenInset;
    }
};
```